# How should I run task with "owner" not shell owner in AIRFLOW

Tags: owner, airflow

My task code is the following.

```
from airflow.models import DAG
from airflow.operators import BashOperator
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
rootdir = "/tmp/airflow"
default_args = {
    'owner': 'max',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': datetime.now(),
    'email': ['max@test.com'],
    'email_on_failure': False,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'retries': 1,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=5),
}
dag = DAG('test3', default_args=default_args,
                    schedule_interval='*/2 * * * *')
t1 = BashOperator(
    task_id='test3-task1',
    bash_command='date  >> {rootdir}/test3-task1.out'.format(rootdir=rootdir),
    owner='max',
    dag=dag)
t2 = BashOperator(
    task_id='test3-task2',
    bash_command='whoami',
    retries=3,
    owner='max',
    dag=dag)
```

Then I run the command "airflow test test3 test3-task2  2016-07-25" with 'airflow' user of linux.   The result of output "whoami" is "airflow".
But I hope that the output result is "owner" of task.

What is my wrong ?

Thanks

the following is the output result.

[2016-07-25 11:22:37,716] {bash_operator.py:64} INFO - Temporary script location :/tmp/airflowtmpoYNJE8//tmp/airflowtmpoYNJE8/test3-task2U1lpom

[2016-07-25 11:22:37,716] {bash_operator.py:65} INFO - Running command: whoami

[2016-07-25 11:22:37,722] {bash_operator.py:73} INFO - Output:

[2016-07-25 11:22:37,725] {bash_operator.py:77} INFO - **airflow**

[2016-07-25 11:22:37,725] {bash_operator.py:80} INFO - Command exited with return code 0

Answer (score 1):

You can use the "run_as_user" parameter under default_args

```
default_args = {
    'owner': 'max',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': datetime.now(),
    'email': ['max@test.com'],
    'email_on_failure': False,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'retries': 1,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=5),
    'run_as_user': 'max'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like what you're trying to do is supported. Looking at the source code for both the [bash_operator](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/master/airflow/operators/bash_operator.py) and the [BaseOperator](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/master/airflow/models.py), neither makes any attempt to change users before executing the task, unfortunately.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Comment: I know this is a very old question, but I was wondering whether this issue has been resolved. I am dealing with this now as part of the `SSHOperator` (reference question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70808086/airflow-dag-with-ssh-connection-cannot-switch-user-su)