# Airflow DAG with SSH connection - cannot switch user (su)

Tags: python, linux, ssh, service, airflow

I have an Airflow (v2) installation and my `graph.py` script in *Box A*. The (Python) codebase of my project lives in *Box B*, so I would like for the Airflow DAG to use a series of [`SSHOperator`](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-ssh/stable/_api/airflow/providers/ssh/operators/ssh/index.html) tasks connecting to *Box B* for the pipeline. The issue is that the codebase lives under a project-specific service account directory, and I would like for each task to be executed by the service account for logging purposes.

#### When I want to execute the code manually in Box B

- I SSH into `Box B` as my *personal* account (which has all privileges). I authenticate with a password.
- `sudo su - <ServiceAccount>` immediately switches me to the service account and moves me to this account's home directory
- I activate the appropriate virtual environment (`source activate ...`)
- I start executing the python scripts of my codebase sequentially: `python run_first.py`, `python run_second.py`, ...`

We want to emulate this whole process using airflow, but unfortunately I have not found a way to switch from my account to the service account within the DAG, nor does `SSHOperator` support `run_as_user` for impersonation, which in my understanding has been deprecated anyway. I have saved my user's password to Airflow as a `password` `Variable` which can be accessed by the graph if/when needed. However, the process fails:

#### When I want to execute the code as a DAG from Box A

- My `graph.py` has an `SSHHook` with the appropriate `ssh_conn_id` (tested, it works)
- Example task in the DAG: `op = SSHOperator(task_id="test", dag=dag, command="whoami", ssh_hook=SSH_HOOK)`. This runs successfully, and I can see from the log that the task does indeed print my personal account username after successfully SSH'ing into `Box B`
- **Failure**: trying to switch to the service account user: `cmd = f"echo {password} | sudo su - S <ServiceAccount>"` (or even without the password) with an exception that the `<ServiceAccount>` does not exist! See log (masked identity of  appropriately):

```
AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_RUN_ID=manual__2022-01-20T18:21:59.493320+00:00
[2022-01-20, 13:22:38 UTC] {ssh.py:135} INFO - Creating ssh_client
[2022-01-20, 13:22:38 UTC] {ssh.py:264} WARNING - Remote Identification Change is not verified. This won't protect against Man-In-The-Middle attacks
[2022-01-20, 13:22:38 UTC] {ssh.py:270} WARNING - No Host Key Verification. This won't protect against Man-In-The-Middle attacks
[2022-01-20, 13:22:38 UTC] {transport.py:1819} INFO - Connected (version 2.0, client OpenSSH_8.0)
[2022-01-20, 13:22:39 UTC] {transport.py:1819} INFO - Authentication (password) successful!
[2022-01-20, 13:22:39 UTC] {ssh.py:139} INFO - Running command: su - <ServiceUser>
[2022-01-20, 13:22:42 UTC] {ssh.py:175} WARNING - su: user <ServiceUser> does not exist
[2022-01-20, 13:22:42 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1686} ERROR - Task failed with exception
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/providers/ssh/operators/ssh.py", line 218, in execute
    result = self.run_ssh_client_command(ssh_client, self.command)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/providers/ssh/operators/ssh.py", line 205, in run_ssh_client_command
    self.raise_for_status(exit_status, agg_stderr)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/providers/ssh/operators/ssh.py", line 201, in raise_for_status
    raise AirflowException(f"error running cmd: {self.command}, error: {error_msg}")
airflow.exceptions.AirflowException: error running cmd: su - <ServiceUser>, error: su: user <ServiceUser> does not exist
```